# Convert api httpresponse bytearray to file

Tags: java, arrays, file, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I am consuming a C# webapi in JAVA.
API method returns an array of file bytes. I can read byte array response in java but when I try to convert the same into file it writes the complete string in file.

Below is the code I am using:

```
HttpResponse response=...
byte[] content = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
File fileToWriteTo = new File("abc.docx");
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(fileToWriteTo, content);
```

Below is the screenshot of file generated:
[DOCX file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qpmB.png)

Below is the fiddler response screenshot:
[Fiddler response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKl9i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Content-Type: application/json

This content/type sent by your C# API is a bit suspicious.

If this end point is supposed to return a byte array, you should receive something like:

> Content-Type: application/octet-stream

So what is happening here is your byte array is sent as a JSON String (noticed the quotes surrounding your bytes?) that is then written as a text file by your Java program.

The best thing to do would be to fix the C# end point to sent the right content-type.

But if you don't have access to it, you can try to parse the JSON String, decode the byte string in a byte array and then write it to a file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You suggestion works for me.